# Recursively find page controls and add attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, recursive-query

I need a recursive function that will find all controls on a page and allow me to add javascript control attributes based on the control type.

The issue is that I have a page with several panels which have controls.  The panels could even have nested panels/controls.

Unfortunately the following doesn't do what I want, but I'm looking for something similar....

```
                Action<Control> traverse = null;

                //in a function:
                traverse = (ctrl) =>
                {
                    //ctrl.Enabled = false; //or whatever action you're performing
                    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
                    {
                        Response.Write(c.GetType().ToString() + " : " + c.ID.ToString() + "<br />");

                        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                        {
                            ((TextBox)(c)).Attributes["onKeypress"] = "javascript:return FormEdited();";
                        }
                        else if (c.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
                        {
                            ((DropDownList)(c)).Attributes["onchange"] = "javascript:return FormEdited();";
                        }
                        else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                        {
                            ((CheckBox)(c)).Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript:return FormEdited();";
                        }

                    }

                    traverse = (ctrl2) => ctrl.Controls.GetEnumerator();
                };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public void traverse(Control ctl)
{
    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c.GetType().ToString());
        //Response.Write(c.GetType().ToString() + " : " + c.ID.ToString() + "<br />"); 
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) 
        { ((TextBox)(c)).Attributes["onKeypress"] = "javascript:return FormEdited();"; 
        } 
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList)) 
        { ((DropDownList)(c)).Attributes["onchange"] = "javascript:return FormEdited();"; 
        } 
        else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)) 
        { ((CheckBox)(c)).Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript:return FormEdited();"; 
        }
        traverse(c);
    }
}
```

and then call it with:

```
traverse(this.Page);
```

i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   traverse(this.Page);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Ultimately I went with a method that uses Linq to flatten all the controls of the page (works if all controls are uniquely named), so I don't have to traverse the hierarchy.